# Save to Drive button cursor

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, google-api, cursor

I have recently added a Google Save to Drive button to my website. I was thoroughly disappointed when I realized that the cursor over the button could not be changed from default to a custom cursor through any CSS or JavaScript means of which I am aware. I have tried all relevant tags, classes and IDs but nothing seems to work. I understand that it is a cross-domain issue, but there has to be a way to get this to work. Might it be possible to replace the style sheet that corresponds to the button with a doctored one? Is there any way that I can change the cursor over this button and maintain its functionality?

Comment: Could you please show us the code of the button? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the cursor to press a `button` you can do it with `cursor` property:

```css
button{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Click Here!</button>
```

If you want to use a custom cursor you can use images to do it with `url` parameter:

```css
button{
  cursor: url(http://www.rw-designer.com/cursor-teaser/tiny.png), auto;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Click Here!</button>
```